# I'm having trouble dropping a migration during a db:reset. Are my migrations incorrect?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, rake

I'm getting this error when I run a db:reset

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::DependentObjectsStillExist: ERROR:  cannot drop table seasons because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint weeks_season_id_fk on table weeks depends on table seasons
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
: DROP TABLE "seasons"
```

The most recent migrations I added were...

```
class AddSeasonIdToWeek < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :weeks, :season_id, :integer, null: false, index: true
  end
end
```

and

```
class AddForeignKeySeasonsToWeeks < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_table :weeks do |a|
      a.foreign_key :seasons
    end
  end
end
```

What do I need to do to get past this error?

Comment: Are you using the foreigner gem to allow foreign key migrations?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this in rails 4:

```
rake db:rollback
```

twice

In older versions of rails (probably 3 and before)

```
rake db:migrate:down
```

twice

Comment: Another option is to just use sql to update the foreign keys in the child records manually to be null and then you can delete the parent records.

Comment: well you could instead just add `dependent: :delete` to the relation, this will nullify the foreign key when deleting

Comment: When you say "twice", do you mean run the command twice, back to back?